# how to set cassandra read and write consistency

Tags: cassandra, consistency

I can not find the documentation for this. I know there is a consistency command in cqlsh, but there is no distinction between read and write consistency. How would I set different consistency levels for read and write?

Furthermore, there is a mention of a "default" consistency level. Where is that default set? and is it for read or write?

Comment: checkout the documentation for the driver you are using like java driver: https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/class-use/ConsistencyLevel.html

Comment: so...where you able to find how its done? google is not helping

Answer (score 5):

By default, the Consistency Level is ONE for all R/W Operations.

Setting CL is done on a per query (read or upsert) basis by adding the `CONSISTENCY XXXX` syntax on the query as seen here:

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#insert

and

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/tools/cqlsh.html

Comment: Both these links are no longer accessible! Can you please update this?

Answer (score 5):

**How would I set different consistency levels for read and write?**

If you just want to change consistency level for your current session, use `CONSISTENCY`.

If you want to change the consistency level programamtically, use the cassandra driver for your client language.

Since the Consistency Level can be set per-statement, you can either set it on every statement, or use PreparedStatements. If you're using the Java driver, you can configure a global Consistency level for BOTH reads and writes (but not *only* reads and *only* writes).

**Where is that default [consistency level] set? and is it for read or write?**

If you want to set up a different consistency level for reads than writes, you'll have to do it on a per-statement basis. Use `QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel` to set a global consistency level (for the Java driver). It is for BOTH reads and writes.

**To set the consistency level for your current session**, use the [CONSISTENCY](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshConsistency.html) command
from the cassandra shell (CQLSH).

For example:

Set CONSISTENCY to force the majority of the nodes to respond:

`CONSISTENCY QUORUM`

To see your current consistency level, just run `CONSISTENCY;` from the shell:

`ty@cqlsh> consistency;
Current consistency level is ONE.`

**For programming client applications**, set the consistency level using an appropriate driver.

To set a *per-insert* consistency level using the Java driver, for example, call `QueryBuilder.insertInto` with `setConsistencyLevel`.

For example:

`PreparedStatement pstmt = session.prepare(
    "INSERT INTO product (sku, description) VALUES (?, ?)");
pstmt.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);`

To set a *global* consistency level for reads AND writes using the Java driver, do something like:

`QueryOptions qo = new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ALL);`

- Since the Java driver only executes CQL statements, which can be either reads or writes to Cassandra, it is not possible to globally configure the Consistency Level for only reads or only writes. To do so, since the Consistency Level can be set per-statement, you can either set it on every statement, or use PreparedStatements. More info in the [Queries and Results](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/upgrade_guide/migrating_from_astyanax/queries_and_results/) document.

**More resources on read/write consistency levels**

- [How consistency level is configured](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html)

  - The different consistency levels are also explained here ^
- [Cassandra's Java Driver documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/)
- See the "Consistency levels" section in [configuring consistency with the Java Driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/upgrade_guide/migrating_from_astyanax/configuration/)

**Other resources on consistency:**
You may also want to look into your replica placement strategy and replication factor (which are other forms of consistency).
I included links below for good measure:

- [Background on data replication in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateKeyspace.html)
- [How to update replica strategy and replication factor using CREATE KEYSPACE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateKeyspace.html)
- [How consistency affects performance](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useTracingPerf.html)

Answer (score 0):

The consistency level is not set anymore with a CQL `USING` clause. See [CASSANDRA-4734](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4734) for an explanation.

Instead, with CQLSH, you should use the `CONSISTENCY` command: see [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/consistency_r.html) for details.

Note that the default consistency level changed in all DataStax drivers from `ONE` to `LOCAL_ONE`: see the [python driver documentation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#setting-a-consistency-level) for details - however, in spite of using the python driver behind the scenes, CQLSH still has a default consistency of `ONE`).

Comment: "ONE to LOCAL_ONE".  Not sure I agree with that; default consistency without setting anything from cqlsh is ONE (output "Current consistency level is ONE").

Comment: You are right, the python driver now defaults to LOCAL_ONE, but cqlsh still defaults to ONE: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/bin/cqlsh.py#L757

Answer (score 0):

The consisenty level is no longer set using **PreparedStatement**. That API was changed. Now you have to use **BatchStatementBuilder**.

Here is sample code that works.

```
BatchStatementBuilder builder = BatchStatement.builder(DefaultBatchType.UNLOGGED);
        builder.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO \"ScottKeySpace16\".\"Movie\" (title, year, plot) values (:k0, :k1, :k2)");
        builder.addStatement(preparedStatement.boundStatementBuilder()
            .setString("k0", "Movie44")
            .setInt("k1", 2022)
            .setString("k2", "This is a very funny movie")
            .build());

        BatchStatement batchStatement = builder.build();
        session.execute(batchStatement);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Default consistency is set in cassandra.conf file . It is for read and write .
2. You can set consistency per query basis adding USING option in query .

Comment: 3 responses. I don't see the answer in any of them. my question is how to set separate read and write consistencies. So I believe the right answer is not to use "using" clause any more, but rather use the consistency command, but my question is how to set different level for read vs. write?

Comment: you just repeated my comment, while not answering the question. I am bewildered this is such a mystery. It can't be that you are forced to set the same consistency level for both read and write. That would make no sense.

Comment: Using cqlsh you can not set . But in java program you can set . In java driver program you find Write conf and Read Conf and also can make Two different cluster and session one for reading and one for writing.

Comment: Ok, next time I come across a Datastax guy, I will definitely post this question to him or her. It definitely sounds like a hold in the product spec.